# Colour blindness simulator

Tags: colors, accessibility, color-blindness

Like any responsible developer, I'd like to make sure that the sites I produce are accessible to the widest possible audience, and that includes the significant fraction of the population with some form of colour blindness.

There are many websites which offer to filter a URL you feed it, either by rendering a picture or by filtering all content. However, both approaches seem to fail when rendering even moderately complex layouts, so I'd be interested in finding a client-side approach.

The ideal solution would be a system filter over the whole screen that can be used to test any program. The next best thing would be a browser plugin.

Comment: See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87146/rgb-filters-for-different-forms-of-color-blindness

Comment: Any luck with finding such a plugin? I'd be very happy to find a ffox plugin that can render everything in black and white (which is actually an extreme form of colour blindness that does exist).

Comment: Sadly not as a Firefox plugin. The best solution so far seems to be the Photoshop plugin version of Vischeck.

Comment: @MarkRansom That older question no longer exists.

Comment: @Tsundoku that's interesting. It was closed and a mod deleted it 11 months ago, even though it was highly voted and had well regarded answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I came across [Color Oracle](http://colororacle.org/) and thought it might help. Here is the short description:

> Color Oracle is a colorblindness simulator for Windows, Mac and Linux. It takes the guesswork out of designing for color blindness by showing you in real time what people with common color vision impairments will see.

Comment: Great tool, but the problem is that it doesn't remain filtered while interacting with the system.  Each time I change a colour I have to go back and reactivate the filter; quite a tedious process.

Comment: Doesn't work on "latest versions of Ubuntu" as per site.

Comment: tl;dr KMag from in the other answer does everything right. -- Color Oracle Site says the latest release is 2018 but it doesn't work correctly at all on Ubuntu. It assumes DPI is 100%, which it's not, so everything is scaled down, then scaled up pixelated. It assumes the top-left corner of the screenshot is the top-left corner of the main screen, which it is not when you have the launcher on top or on left, or if the second screen is vertically offset. But worst of all, it's not real-time like first commenter said.

Comment: Seems to be a great tool, but doesn't work well with a multi screen setup. KMag works great for me.

Answer (score 9):

Color Oracle is great, but another option is [KMag](https://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kmag/), which is part of KDE in Linux. It's ostensibly a screen magnifier, but can simulate protanopia, deuteranopia, tritanopia and achromatopsia.

It differs from Color Oracle by requiring an additional window in which to display the re-coloured image, but an advantage is that one can modify the underlying image at the same time as previewing the simulation.

Here is a screenshot showing the original figure on the left, and the KMag window on the right, simulating protanopia.

[image]

Comment: Just tested on Ubuntu 22.04LTS, both the apt and the snap version, none worked (image is gray).

Comment: @Arnaud I'm not really sure what to say. I just tested in Arch, running the latest KMag 22.12.0, and it works fine. Are you in protanopia? Otherwise, perhaps consider filing a bug upstream?

Comment: I tested different colorblindness modes and none worked. I will file a bug if I find the time to. Meanwhile I found my more Internet search that Firefox's developer tools now has colorblindness simulator in its accessibility options. Since 90% of my development is for the web, this solves most of my concerns.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a link to a website that simulates various kinds of color blindness:

http://www.vischeck.com/

They let you check URL's and Screenshots with three kinds of different color blindness types (URL checking is a bit dated though. Image-check works better).

I'd encourage everyone to check their applications btw. Seeing your own app with others eyes may be an eye opener (pun intended).

Comment: Like I said in the question, it mangles my layouts so much that it's hard to tell anything. For example, it misses out background pictures, replaces transparent images with ones on a white background, changes fonts, etc.

I can run it on a screenshot that I've saved, but as a live simulator it fails

Comment: I've marked you as the answer even though it's not what I asked for. The Photoshop plugin they have for Vischeck is a lot better than the online version, and is the closest solution I've found.

Comment: Sorry for un-marking you as the answer, but a better one turned up. VisCheck is still a valuable tool, but Color Oracle is brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a quite old question, but I've recently found an interesting solution to transparently simulate color blindness.

When working with Linux, you can simulate color blindness using the [Color Filter](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Colorfilter) plugin for Compiz. It comes with profiles for deuteranopia and protonopia und changes the colors of the whole screen in real-time.

It's very nice because it works transparently in all applications (even within Youtube-Videos), but it will only work where Compiz is available, e.g. only under Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article that has some guidelines for optimizing UI for color blind users:

[Particletree » Be Kind to the Color Blind](http://particletree.com/features/interfaces-and-color-blindness/)

It contains a link to another article with the kind of tools you were asking for:

[10 colour contrast checking tools to improve the accessibility of your design | 456 Berea Street](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/10_colour_contrast_checking_tools_to_improve_the_accessibility_of_your_design/)

Answer (score 1):

A great paper that explains a conversion that preserves color differences is:

[Detail Preserving Reproduction of color images for Monochromats and Dichromats.(PDF)](http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~geist/recent_papers/g3geis.pdf)

I haven't implemented the filter, but I plan to when I have some more free time.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Colour Simulations](http://www.coloursimulations.com/) easy to use on Windows 10. This software can apply a color-blind filter to a part of the screen or the whole screen. And what's great is it allows me to interact with my PC normally as if it doesn't exist in fullscreen mode. It runs quite slow in my 4K screen using an integrated graphics card, though.