# Color Blindness Simulator

Tags: firefox-addon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Colour blindness simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203296/colour-blindness-simulator)

Can anyone recommend a good development tool for testing the affects of colorblindness in applications?
A search of SO and Google didn't come up with anything. I am working on a web page and don't have admin privileges so a Mozilla add-on would be ideal.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203296/colour-blindness-simulator